# Transform complicated string based on criteria in python and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a column that contains a complicated string format. I would like to keep the first word only, and/or keep the first word in addition to certain other words.

I wish to keep certain key words in the string, such as  'RED', 'DB', 'APP', 'Infra', etc.

***DATA***

```
type                                         grp

Goodbye-CCC-LET-TestData-A.1                 a
Hello-PIR-SSS-Hellosims-App-INN-A.0          b
Hello-PIR-SSS-DB-RED-INN-C.0                 c
Hello-PIR-SSS-App-SA200-F.0                  d
Goodbye-PIR-SIR-DB_set-int-e.1               c
OK-PIR-SVV-Infra_ll-NA-A.0                   e
```

***DESIRED***

```
type                                        grp

Goodbye                                     a
Hello-App                                   b
Hello-DB-RED                                c
Hello-App                                   d
Goodbye-DB                                  c
OK-Infra                                    e
```

***DOING***

```
s = (df['type'].str.split('-')
               .str[0]
               .str.cat(rack['type'].str.extract(r'(\d.\d+T|\d+T)', expand=False), 
                        sep=' ', 
                        na_rep='')
               .str.strip())

df.insert(1, 'type', s)
```

The following code just give me the first word, for example:

```
Goodbye
Hello
OK
```

Any suggestion is appreciated. I am still researching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `str.extractall` on your series then join the values

```
import pandas as pd
import re 

df.drop('type',1).join(df['type'].str.extractall('(^\w+)-|(app|red|infra|db)'
                          ,flags=re.IGNORECASE)\
                          .stack()\
                          .groupby(level=0)\
                          .agg(type='-'.join))


  grp          type
0   a       Goodbye
1   b     Hello-App
2   c  Hello-DB-RED
3   d     Hello-App
4   c    Goodbye-DB
5   e      OK-Infra
```

Comment: Thank you @Manakin - what does the drop do? Is it dropping one of the columns, and then the number 1 adds it back?

Comment: @Lynn you're very welcome. `drop` is dropping `type` from your original dataframe `df1` the `1` is n argument for axis i.e we want to drop `type` from the column. then `type` is re-added via the `join` `.groupby(level=0)` groups along your index meaning we can join on your original index.

Comment: Ah ok makes sense. I will play around with this script  . Thank you